# where exactly in the network are routers and switches used?

Tags: networking

what is the difference between routers and switches?
i know that switches use MAC address and routers use IP address, can anybody elaborate and tell where exactly in the network switches and routers are used? what is the need for switches when routers exist?

Comment: have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 0):

Source [What is a Network Switch vs. a Router?](http://www.cisco.com/cisco/web/solutions/small_business/resource_center/articles/connect_employees_and_offices/what_is_a_network_switch/index.html?referring_site=smartnavRD)

> **What is a network switch and what is a router?**
>
> The two pieces of equipment look similar and perform some similar
>   functions, but each has its own distinct function to perform on a
>   network.
>
> **What is a Network Switch?**
>
> Most business networks today use switches to connect computers,
>   printers and servers within a building or campus. A switch serves as a
>   controller, enabling networked devices to talk to each other
>   efficiently. Through information sharing and resource allocation,
>   switches save businesses money and increase employee productivity.
>
> **Unmanaged Switches**
>
> An unmanaged switch works right out of the box. It's not designed to
>   be configured, so you don't have to worry about installing or setting
>   it up correctly. Unmanaged switches have less network capacity than
>   managed switches. You'll usually find unmanaged switches in home
>   networking equipment.
>
> **Managed Switches**
>
> A managed network switch is configurable, offering greater flexibility
>   and capacity than an unmanaged switch. You can monitor and adjust a
>   managed switch locally or remotely, to give you greater network
>   control.
>
> **What is a Network Switch versus a Router?**
>
> Switches create a network. Routers connect networks.
>
> A router links computers to the Internet, so users can share the
>   connection. A router acts as a dispatcher, choosing the best path for
>   information to travel so it's received quickly.

Summary

**Switches create a network. Routers connect networks.**